# Validar campo y no cerrar el formulario

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy trabajando en un plugin para [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis), en el formulario el usuario ingresa los datos y uno de ellos es el nombre del archivo, asi que valido el campo y verifico que no exista el mismo nombre, el problema es que si existe muestra un mensaje y se cierra el formulario, no permitiendo que el usuario pueda modificar dicho nombre.

La funcion que verifica el nombre del documento es la siguiente:

```
def verificaArchivo(self,file):

   documentoNuevo = os.path.isfile(file)

   if documentoNuevo is True:
       QMessageBox.information(None, "ERROR", "El nombre {} ya EXISTE!".format(self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()))
   else:
    return False
```

Y aca es donde se ejecuta

```
def run(self):
    """
   QMessageBox.information(None, "valores", ",".join([str(x[0]) for x in cursorLista]))
   QMessageBox.information(None, "valores", "idLote={}".format(self.dlg.lote.text()))

    """
    self.dlg.lote.clear()
    self.dlg.referencia.clear()
    self.dlg.nombreArchivo.clear()
    self.dlg.orden.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.desLote.clear()

    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.buscaDescripcion)

    ix = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    idSeccion = self.dlg.comboBox.itemData(ix)

    self.dlg.show()

    # Run the dialog event loop

    result = self.dlg.exec_()

    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:

        #Guarda imagen en servidor

        rutaArchivo = "D:/temp/"+"Lote-"+self.dlg.lote.text()+"_"+self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()+".png"

        resulArchivo = self.verificaArchivo(rutaArchivo)

        if resulArchivo is False:

            self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(rutaArchivo)
            self.insertaInformes(self.dlg.lote.text(),self.dlg.referencia.toPlainText(),self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()+".png",idSeccion,self.dlg.orden.text())

        pass
```

Como puedo lograr que si la funcion retorna True, permita al usuario modificar el nombre del documento en self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()

```
class SaveInformesDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(SaveInformesDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Codigo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>SaveInformesDialogBase</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="SaveInformesDialogBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>516</width>
    <height>355</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>GuardaInformes</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>330</x>
     <y>310</y>
     <width>171</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Referencia</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="orden">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>230</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Numero Lote</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>230</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Orden</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Seccion</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="nombreArchivo">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>270</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lote">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>270</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Nombre Archivo</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="referencia">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>121</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="desLote">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>240</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>261</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>SaveInformesDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>SaveInformesDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Comment: Tú estas verificando el dato despues de cerrarse el dialogo, ¿tú quieres que se reabra el dialogo?

Comment: Si, shora mismo valida y cierra el formulario, que lo reabra o permita modificar el campo invalido sin cerrar la ventana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de evitar que se cierre la ventana es deshabilitar el boton Ok que cierra el dialogo, para ello usamos setDisabled(), usamos la señal textChanged() de los QLineEdit para hacer esa tarea:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    ...
    self.dlg = SaveInformesDialog()
    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.buscaDescripcion)
    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.verificar)
    self.dlg.nombreArchivo.textChanged.connect(self.verificar)

...

def run(self):
    self.dlg.lote.clear()
    self.dlg.referencia.clear()
    self.dlg.nombreArchivo.clear()
    self.dlg.orden.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.desLote.clear()

    ix = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    idSeccion = self.dlg.comboBox.itemData(ix)

    # Run the dialog event loop

    result = self.dlg.exec_()

    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(rutaArchivo)
        self.insertaInformes(self.dlg.lote.text(),self.dlg.referencia.toPlainText(),self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()+".png",idSeccion,self.dlg.orden.text())

def verificar(self):
    rutaArchivo = "D:/temp/Lote-{}_{}.png".format(self.dlg.lote.text(), self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text())
    existe_archivo = os.path.isfile(rutaArchivo)

    btn = self.dlg.button_box.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    btn.setDisabled(existe_archivo)
```

Comment: Tengo el siguiente error 'SaveInformesDialog' object has no attribute 'indChild'

Comment: @Sebastian ya lo arregle, fue un typo.

Comment: ahora me salio lo siguiente 
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   findChild(self, type, name: str = '', options: Union[Qt.FindChildOptions, Qt.FindChildOption] = Qt.FindChildrenRecursively): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QDialogButtonBox'   findChild(self, Tuple, name: str = '', options: Union[Qt.FindChildOptions, Qt.FindChildOption] = Qt.FindChildrenRecursively): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QDialogButtonBox'

Comment: btn = self.dlg.findChild(self.dlg.button_box).button(self.dlg.button_box.Ok)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  findChild(self, type, name: str = '', options: Union[Qt.FindChildOptions, Qt.FindChildOption] = Qt.FindChildrenRecursively): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QDialogButtonBox'
  findChild(self, Tuple, name: str = '', options: Union[Qt.FindChildOptions, Qt.FindChildOption] = Qt.FindChildrenRecursively): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QDialogButtonBox'

Comment: comparte el codigo de SaveInformesDialog.

Comment: Lo incorpore a la pregunta

Comment: @Sebastian nunca compartas codigo en los comentarios, ¿crees que es legible?, edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli

Comment: @Sebastian muestra el codigo de FORM_CLASS, necesito obtener la informacion de los widgets

Comment: Añadido el codigo

Comment: @Sebastian ya he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Funciono perfecto, como siempre gracias por tu tiempo y dedicacion